# number approximation in python

Tags: python, numbers, graph-theory

I have a list of floating points numbers which represent x and y coordinates of points.

```
(-379.99418604651157, 47.517234218543351, 0.0) #representing point x
```

an edge contains two such numbers.

I'd like to use a graph traversal algorithm, such as dijkstra, but using floating point numbers such as the ones above don't help. 
What I'm actually looking for is a way of approximating those numbers:

```
(-37*.*, 4*.*, 0.0)
```

is there a python function that does that?

Comment: from fpformat import fix

Comment: @Ant: `fix()` returns a string.  Furthermore, `fpformat` is deprecated since Pyhon 2.6 and removed in Python 3.

Comment: i knew that fix returns a string, but not that it is deprecated; thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so?

```
>>> x, y, z = (-379.99418604651157, 47.517234218543351, 0.0)
>>> abs(x - -370) < 10
True
>>> abs(y - 40) < 10
True
```

Comment: No, consider `x, y, z = (-3000, -3000, 0)`. They also pass your test. You need to use `abs(x - -370) < 10`. That'll accept -360 to -380.

Comment: for further abstraction. How can I read the first two digits in x?

Comment: @bsuv: That's a different question, and it requires you do convert the number to a string, which is a heavy process, comparatively. So: DOn't. :-)

Comment: I corrected the parentheses. Previous version would have passed `x, y, z = (370, -40, 0)`.

Comment: I love how I get the choice of correct answer, but not a single upvote. :-)

Answer (score 2):

"...using floating point numbers such as the ones above don't help..." - why not?  I don't recall integers as a requirement for Dijkstra.  Aren't you concerned with the length of the edge?  That's more likely to be a floating point number, even if the endpoints are expressed in integer values.

I'm quoting from Steve Skiena's "Algorithm Design Manual":

> Dijkstra's algorithm proceeds in a
>   series of rounds, where each round
>   establishes the shortest path from s
>   to some new vertex.  Specifically, x
>   is the vertex that minimizes dist(s,
>   vi) + w(vi, x) over all unfinished 1
>   <= i <= n...

*Distance* - no mention of integer.

Comment: The issue is in the points of the nodes and edges not being connected. Those points are generated by a user who simply draws a line, and (s)he thinks of that as being an edge. For the algorithm to work the edges have to be connected/intersected, but when there's an edge that starts at node -379.99418604651157, 47.517234218543351, 0.0 and another that starts at -379.993, 47.5171, 0.0 although, seemingly they appear connected on the map, because of their position details they're not an edge in a graph. Dijkstra explores the edges connected to a node.I'm trying to set a radius around those values

Comment: You should deal with epsilons, absolute and relative errors whenever you use floating point numbers.  You can't check equality; you need to check proximity within some error bound.  None of this has anything to do with Dijkstra; you need to check the connectivity of your graph before you start the calculations.  It's a pre-processing step when you read in the graph.  Just be careful that the epsilon you choose is large enough to close up errors, but not so large that you detect and collapse two points that should be distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Given your vector

```
(-379.99418604651157, 47.517234218543351, 0.0) #representing point x
```

The easiest way to perform rounding that works like you would expect would probably be to use the decimal module: http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html .

```
from decimal import Decimal:
point = (-379.99418604651157, 47.517234218543351, 0.0) #representing point x
converted = [Decimal(str(x)) for x in point]
```

Then, to get an approximation, you can use the quantize method:

```
>>> converted[0].quantize(Decimal('.0001'), rounding="ROUND_DOWN")
Decimal("-379.9941")
```

This approach has the advantage of the built in ability to avoid rounding errors. Hopefully this is helpful.

Edit:

After seeing your comment, it looks like you're trying to see if two points are close to each other. These functions might do what you want:

```
def roundable(a,b):
    """Returns true if a can be rounded to b at any precision"""
    a = Decimal(str(a))
    b = Decimal(str(b))
    return a.quantize(b) == b

def close(point_1, point_2):
    for a,b in zip(point_1, point_2):
        if not (roundable(a,b) or roundable(b,a)):
            return False
    return True
```

I don't know if this is better than an epsilon approach, but it's fairly simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is with the floating point numbers, but there are several ways you can approximate your values. If you just want to round them you can use `math.ceil()`, `math.floor()` and `math.trunc()`.

If you actually want to keep track of the precision, there are a bunch of multi-precision math libraries [listed on the wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific#Multiprecisionmath) which might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to approximate the number so that you can visually easily understand you're algorithm while stepping into it (as Djikstra pose no limitation on the coordinate of the node, in fact it is only interested with the cost of edges).

A simple function to approximate numbers:

```
>>> import math
>>> def approximate(value, places = 0):
...     factor = 10. ** places
...     return factor * math.trunc(value / factor)
>>> p = (-379.99418604651157, 47.517234218543351, 0.0)
>>> print [ approximate(x, 1) for x in p ]
[-370.0, 40.0, 0.0]
```